# Sliding a notification to the right causes an action to be performed on iOS 10

Tags: apple-push-notifications, ios10

I'm testing my iOS 9 app on the new iOS 10 beta 1. When I slide one of my app's notifications to the right on the lockscreen, it causes one of my notification actions to be performed instead of just opening the app like it always did.

Anybody else experiencing this? If so please let me know if you find a workaround.

Comment: Also, please file a bug report with Apple if you are also experiencing this! (I did myself already)

Comment: After doing more investigation it turns out handleActionWithIdentifier called instead of didReceiveRemoteNotification when app is running but not in foreground. I really, really hope this is a bug and not some unannounced change in the API :/ I've also posted a copy of my bug report with more detail and why it should be considered a bug at https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4960493114490880